# How to rename the text field placeholder

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Im using SCLAlertView and i would to rename the text field placeholder if the user not entering any input at the text field.

```
func reloadAlertView(msg : String){
        // Create custom Appearance Configuration
        let appearance = SCLAlertView.SCLAppearance(
            kTitleFont: UIFont(name: "Play", size: 14)!,
            kTextFont: UIFont(name: "Play", size: 14)!,
            kButtonFont: UIFont(name: "Play", size: 14)!,
            showCircularIcon: false
        )
        let alert = SCLAlertView(appearance:appearance)
        email = alert.addTextField("Enter email")
        email.text = tempEmail
        alert.addButton("Submit", target: self, selector: #selector(LoginViewController.forgotPasswordBtnPressed))
        alert.showEdit("Forgot Password", subTitle: msg, colorStyle: 0xFF0000, closeButtonTitle : "Close")         
    }

    func forgotPasswordBtnPressed(){

        let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"

        _ = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)

        if email.text == ""{
            reloadAlertView("Please fill all field")
        }else{
            validationSuccessful()
        }     
    }
```

i would like to rename the textfield instead of using this

```
email = alert.addTextField("Enter email")
```

to this when user input a blank space and click submit

```
email = alert.addTextField("Please fill this")
```

Comment: can you attach your project here

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik can u check my answer. i got one more question in it

Answer (score 0):

I able to make it rename the field by calling the same syntax as the first one

```
if email.text == ""{
            let appearance = SCLAlertView.SCLAppearance(
                kTitleFont: UIFont(name: "Play", size: 14)!,
                kTextFont: UIFont(name: "Play", size: 14)!,
                kButtonFont: UIFont(name: "Play", size: 14)!,
                showCircularIcon: false
            )
            let alert = SCLAlertView(appearance:appearance)
            email = alert.addTextField("You maybe forget this")
            email.text = tempEmail
            alert.addButton("Submit", target: self, selector: #selector(LoginViewController.forgotPasswordBtnPressed))
            alert.showEdit("Forgot Password", subTitle: "Please fill all field", colorStyle: 0xFF0000, closeButtonTitle : "Close")
        }
```

one more question how can i rename the string to redColor?

```
email = alert.addTextField("You maybe forget this")
email.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Comment: chekthe modify answer at the same time on textfied begining change the textcolre if textfield.text.length >0

Comment: can you attach your project